# Can FTL modify the request object setting an attribute?

Tags: servlet-filters, freemarker

I know that FTL is purely a rendering engine and this should be done in the controller but 
in my scenario I need to provide multiple representations of the same data.

I can write easily FTL that renders XML and then is converted to JSON if needed by a custom filter. However we have tons of FTL to do. The data model is going to be generic. Althought the XML approach is an option I would not like  to repeat over and over the same XML elements, ( different team members writing handcrafter xml elements is a recipe for errors, we need to be sure that the markup is the same,etc)

However I was wondering if I can do just populate an object in my FTL

//Assume a FreMarkerResolver has exposed my output metamodel as part of the model
someObject.addRecords( Records)

//some logic here
request.setAttribute("data",someObject);

So then my Servlet filter will just convert the data object into JSON, xml, YAML or whatever i want.

I´ve read somewhere that for example session cannot be modified from FTL but what about request? Can we at least set a new attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker itself knows nothing about Servlets or HTTP. Even when you can just read the request or session objects, that's already the higher level Web Application Framework's doing. It's completely up to the Web Application Framework if, and how do you see those objects from templates, and so it's up to it if there are methods to modify them. Now I will assume there aren't in your case.

You could create a `TemplateDirectiveModel` that encapsulates the `Request` and does what you want with it, and drop it into the data-model, say, with name `storeInRequest`, so you can do something like `<@storeInRequest data=someObject />` in the template. Or you can figure out something else that expresses better what you want in that app. The point is that since the `TemplateDirectiveModel` is implemented in Java, you have power to do anything inside it. (Similarly, you can implement function-like stuff with `TemplateMethodModelEx`, but if you need a side-effect instead of a return value then `TemplateDirectiveModel` is nicer. Plus it has named parameters...)